# Issue with uploading Preview image on Ooyala

Tags: upload, thumbnails, ooyala

I am using Ooyala sdk for C# and got a problem with uploading image for specific content. Here is my code. will be happy to get some help:

```
OoyalaAPI o = new OoyalaAPI(apikey, secretkey);         
byte[] bytess = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\FIRE2.jpg");
Hashtable booody = new Hashtable();           
string exception = "";
object p = o.postBytes("assets/I2ZDlzbjrIFtbAxzrkJ3NLzEDR30jFYh/preview_image_urls", new Dictionary<string, string>(), bytess, out exception, null);   //Upload File              
booody.Add("type", "uploaded_file");
o.put("assets/I2ZDlzbjrIFtbAxzrkJ3NLzEDR30jFYh/primary_preview_image", new Dictionary<string, string>(), booody, out exception); //Pick The Thumbnail File
```

The Exception i get is (400) Bad Request from the function response = request.GetResponse() 
as HttpWebResponse;

I will appreciate some help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Changed preview_image_urls to preview_image_files...
Works good now.